# Conversion of tense in interrogative sentence from direct to indirect speech

Tags: tense, questions, reported-speech

> 1. "Can you see a woman seated at a table?" he asked.
>    A) He asked her if she could see a woman seated at a table.

Since the reported speech is in past tense, the tense of the indirect speech should be in past perfect. But there is no *had* in it.

Please clarify my doubt. I guess it is in past since the word seated is used.

Comment: The reported speech isn't in the past tense.

Comment: The word seated is used right

Comment: The question being asked is "Can you see...?" which is present tense.

Comment: If he had said "Can you see the woman who has just sat down at the table?", THEN the reported speech would be _He asked her if she could see the woman who had just sat down at the table_.

Comment: _Seated_ is **not** past here: it is an adjective, and has no tense.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that these sentences are written at 9:00 and that the actions that they describe occurred at 8:00. In that case, both sentences are correct. In the second sentence, both verbs are in the past tense<sup>1</sup>:

> He **asked** her if she **could see** a woman seated at a table.

If her action happened at 7:00, then it would be better to put the verb describing her action into the perfect aspect:

> He **asked** her if she **could have seen** a woman seated at a table.

However, modal verbs can be tricky and are often ambiguous. (In this case, "could have" might mean the same as "might have".) Therefore, this would be clearer:

> He **asked** her if she **had been able to see** a woman seated at a table.

---

<sup>1</sup>I actually prefer to use the term "preterite" for modal auxiliaries, but that's a different issue.